# Secure data for NodeJs interface

Tags: metamask, security, nodejs

I want to secure data for my NodeJs+Express+Mongodb website :

- ABI
- Contract address
- Infura.io API key

Those data are very important because if an attacker can change them, it can steal ETH from my user.

Is there a way to run NodeJs with ABI+Contract address encrypted, and decrypt them with a passphrase ?
Or can I store a file with this 2 data that need root access to be modified ?

Answer (score 0):

> Those data are very important because if an attacker can change them, it can steal ETH from my user.

This is incorrect. Only exposing a private key can lead to lost assets.

> Is there a way to run NodeJs with ABI+Contract address encrypted, and decrypt them with a passphrase ?

ABI and contract address are already public information and there is no point to encrypt them.